# How to return calendar using this method

Tags: java, date, calendar

I want return calendar type object but while parsing from String to Date type,Its changing the format.

```
public static Calendar Dateandtime(Timestamp timeStamp) throws ParseException {
    Calendar tempCal = new GregorianCalendar();
    SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd 'T' hh:mm:ss.SSS z");
    String date1 = ft.format(timeStamp.getTime());
    System.out.println("***String date ***"+date1);
    Date d = ft.parse(date1);
    tempCal.setTime(d);
    System.out.println("*****Date *****"+tempCal.getTime());
    System.out.println("*****Calendar *****"+tempCal);
    return tempCal;
}
```

## Ouput

```
   ***String date ***2014.09.11 T 03:58:25.00  IST
    *****Date *****Thu Sep 11 03:58:25 IST 
 *****Calendar****java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1410388105000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",offset=19800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=6,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=37,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=11,DAY_OF_YEAR=254,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=3,MINUTE=58,SECOND=25,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

But I want this format 2014.09.11 T 03:58:25.00  IST.

How to achieve this using above code any help regarding this.

Where as my output should be 2014.09.11 T 03:58:25.00  IST

Comment: you need to format your output with the Calendar object methods.
for eg,
to get timezone 

tempCal.getTimeZone() and then display it using 'syso'

Answer (score -1):

The calendar object does not hold formatting information.
As per your code, you have already obtained the data in your required format, from the following lines:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy.MM.dd 'T' hh:mm:ss.SSS z");
String date1 = ft.format(timeStamp.getTime());
System.out.println("***String date ***"+date1);
```